# Multiple Table Headers Within a Header

Tags: html, css, html-table

My HTML table has a special header which contains 3 subheaders with its own table rows. I tried to accomplish it using `rowspan` and `colspan` but I am getting lost in between. I will try my best to illustrate what I am trying to achieve using HTML table.

```
/-------------------------------------------------------------\
|          |              Two             |         |         |
|  One     |------------------------------|  Three  |  Four   |
|          |  Two A  |  Two B   |  Two C  |         |         |
|-----------------------------------------|---------|---------|
|  1.0     | 20.00   |   40.00  |  52.00  |    45   |   62    |
|-----------------------------------------|---------|---------|
|  2.0     | 60.00   |   70.00  |  84.00  |    54   |   45    |
\-------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Can this be done using only HTML tables or do I need to tray any other methods?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution with just rowspan and colspan

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        th,
        td {
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">One</th>
            <th colspan="3">Two</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Three</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Four</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Two A</th>
            <th>Two B</th>
            <th>Two C</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.0</td><td>10.00</td><td>40.00</td><td>52.00</td><td>40</td><td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.0</td><td>60.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>84.0</td><td>54</td><td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for. IF so you need to nest a table in your table header.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>1</th><th colspan="2">MAIN<table><tr><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table></th><th>4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```